# Implementing Binary Cross Entropy loss gives different answer than Tensorflow's

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am implementing the **Binary Cross-Entropy** loss function with Raw python but it gives me a very different answer than Tensorflow.
This is the answer I got from Tensorflow:-

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy

y_true = np.array([1., 1., 1.])
y_pred = np.array([1., 1., 0.])
bce = BinaryCrossentropy()
loss = bce(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss.numpy())
```

Output:

```
>>> 5.1416497230529785
```

From my Knowledge, the formula of Binary Cross entropy is this:

[image]

I implemented the same with raw python as follows:

```
def BinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred):
    m = y_true.shape[1]
    y_pred = np.clip(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    # Calculating loss
    loss = -1/m * (np.dot(y_true.T, np.log(y_pred)) + np.dot((1 - y_true).T, np.log(1 - y_pred)))

    return loss

print(BinaryCrossEntropy(np.array([1, 1, 1]).reshape(-1, 1), np.array([1, 1, 0]).reshape(-1, 1)))
```

But from this function I get loss value to be:

```
>>> [[16.11809585]]
```

How can I get the right answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some issue with your implementation. Here is the correct one with `numpy`.

```
def BinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = np.clip(y_pred, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    term_0 = (1-y_true) * np.log(1-y_pred + 1e-7)
    term_1 = y_true * np.log(y_pred + 1e-7)
    return -np.mean(term_0+term_1, axis=0)

print(BinaryCrossEntropy(np.array([1, 1, 1]).reshape(-1, 1), 
                         np.array([1, 1, 0]).reshape(-1, 1)))
[5.14164949]
```

Note, during the `tf. keras` model training, it's better to use `keras` backend functionality. You can implement it, in the same way, using the `keras` backend utilities.

```
def BinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred + K.epsilon())  
    term_1 = y_true * K.log(y_pred + K.epsilon())
    return -K.mean(term_0 + term_1, axis=0)

print(BinaryCrossEntropy(
    np.array([1., 1., 1.]).reshape(-1, 1), 
    np.array([1., 1., 0.]).reshape(-1, 1)
    ).numpy())
[5.14164949]
```

Comment: `np.clip` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, but if you see the question, the OP did. The answer was for him.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question. Why is there a different answer with the changing of epsilon? How would I know it's `1e-7` that's needed to implement it correctly?

Comment: This does answer the given question. The OP wants to match scores between official method to his custom method. Now, if you look at the src code of the official implementation, you would see `1e-7` is added, [src](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/601488fd4c1468ae7872e132e0f1c9843df54182/keras/backend_config.py#L26-L44).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the source code. That was my mistake. I used another constant.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`, you'll notice,

```
tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0, reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
    name='binary_crossentropy'
)
```

The default argument `reduction` will most probably have the value `Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`, as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy#args). Assume that the shape of our model outputs is `[ 1 , 3 ]`. Meaning, our batch size is 1 and the output dims is 3 ( This does not imply that there are 3 classes ). We need to compute the mean over the 0th axis i.e. the batch dimension.

I'll make it clear with the code,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array( [1., 1., 1.] ).reshape( 1 , 3 )
y_pred = np.array( [1., 1., 0.] ).reshape( 1 , 3 )

bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy( from_logits=False , reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE )
loss = bce( y_true, y_pred )

print(loss.numpy())
```

The output is,

```
5.1416497230529785
```

The expression for Binary Crossentropy is the same as mentioned in the question. N refers to the batch size.

We now implement BCE on our own. First, we clip the outputs of our model, setting `max` to `tf.keras.backend.epsilon()` and `min` to `1 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon()`. The value of `tf.keras.backend.epsilon()` is 1e-7.

```
y_pred = np.clip( y_pred , tf.keras.backend.epsilon() , 1 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon() )
```

Using the expression for BCE,

```
p1 = y_true * np.log( y_pred + tf.keras.backend.epsilon() )
p2 = ( 1 - y_true ) * np.log( 1 - y_pred + tf.keras.backend.epsilon() )

print( p1 )
print( p2 )
```

The output,

```
[[  0.           0.         -15.42494847]]
[[-0. -0.  0.]]
```

Notice that the shapes are still preserved. A `np.dot` will turn them into a array of two elements i.e. of shape `[ 1 , 2 ]` ( As in your implementation ).

Finally, we add them and compute their mean using `np.mean()` over the batch dimension,

```
o  = -np.mean( p1 + p2 )
print( o )
```

The output is,

```
5.141649490132791
```

You can check the problem in your implementation by printing the `shape` of each of the terms.