# tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy gives different values than plain implementation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, implementation, tf.keras, cross-entropy

Any one knows why raw implementation of Categorical Crossentropy function is so different from the `tf.keras`'s api function?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math
tf.enable_eager_execution()

y_true =np.array( [[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]])
y_pred = np.array([[.9, .05, .05], [.5, .89, .6], [.05, .01, .94]])

ce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
res = ce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
print("use api:")
print(res)

print()
print("implementation:")
step1 = -y_true * np.log(y_pred )
step2 = np.sum(step1, axis=1)

print("step1.shape:", step1.shape)
print(step1)
print("sum step1:", np.sum(step1, ))
print("mean step1", np.mean(step1))

print()
print("step2.shape:", step2.shape)
print(step2)
print("sum step2:", np.sum(step2, ))
print("mean step2", np.mean(step2))
```

Above gives:

```
use api:
0.3239681124687195

implementation:
step1.shape: (3, 3)
[[0.10536052 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.11653382 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.0618754 ]]
sum step1: 0.2837697356318653
mean step1 0.031529970625762814

step2.shape: (3,)
[0.10536052 0.11653382 0.0618754 ]
sum step2: 0.2837697356318653
mean step2 0.09458991187728844
```

If now with another `y_true` and `y_pred`:

```
y_true = np.array([[0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.99999999999, 0.00000000001]])
```

It gives:

```
use api:
16.11809539794922

implementation:
step1.shape: (1, 2)
[[-0.         25.32843602]]
sum step1: 25.328436022934504
mean step1 12.664218011467252

step2.shape: (1,)
[25.32843602]
sum step2: 25.328436022934504
mean step2 25.328436022934504
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67615051/10878733) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because of these values: `[.5, .89, .6]`, since it's sum is not equal to 1. I think you have made a mistake and you meant this instead: `[.05, .89, .06]`.

If you provide the values with sum equal to 1, then both formulas results will be the same:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array( [[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]])
y_pred = np.array([[.9, .05, .05], [.05, .89, .06], [.05, .01, .94]])

print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print(np.sum(-y_true * np.log(y_pred), axis=1))

#output
#[0.10536052 0.11653382 0.0618754 ]
#[0.10536052 0.11653382 0.0618754 ]
```

However, let's explore how is calculated if the `y_pred` tensor is not scaled (the sum of values is not equal to 1)? If you look at the source code of categorical cross entropy [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/85fe6427a50f6def7777413a4bc8b286f7ab8f8d/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2729), you will see that it scales `y_pred` so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1:

```
if not from_logits:
    # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
    output /= tf.reduce_sum(output,
                            reduction_indices=len(output.get_shape()) - 1,
                            keep_dims=True)
```

since we passed a pred which the sum of probas is not 1, let's see how this operation changes our tensor `[.5, .89, .6]`:

```
output =  tf.constant([.5, .89, .6])
output /= tf.reduce_sum(output,
                            axis=len(output.get_shape()) - 1,
                            keepdims=True)
print(output.numpy())

# array([0.2512563 , 0.44723618, 0.30150756], dtype=float32)
```

So, it should be equal if we replace the above operation output (scaled `y_pred`), and pass it to your own implemented categorical cross entropy, with the unscaled `y_pred` passing to tensorflow implementation:

```
y_true =np.array( [[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]])

#unscaled y_pred
y_pred = np.array([[.9, .05, .05], [.5, .89, .6], [.05, .01, .94]])  
print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())

#scaled y_pred (categorical_crossentropy scales above tensor to this internally)
y_pred = np.array([[.9, .05, .05], [0.2512563 , 0.44723618, 0.30150756], [.05, .01, .94]])  
print(np.sum(-y_true * np.log(y_pred), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
[0.10536052 0.80466845 0.0618754 ]
[0.10536052 0.80466846 0.0618754 ]
```

Now, let's explore the results of your second example. Why your second example shows different output?
If you check the source code again, you will see this line:

```
output = tf.clip_by_value(output, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)
```

which clips values below than a threshold. Your input `[0.99999999999, 0.00000000001]` will be converted to `[0.9999999, 0.0000001]` in this line, so it gives you a different result:

```
y_true = np.array([[0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[0.99999999999, 0.00000000001]])

print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print(np.sum(-y_true * np.log(y_pred), axis=1))

#now let's first clip the values less than epsilon, then compare loss
epsilon=1e-7
y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)
print(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
print(np.sum(-y_true * np.log(y_pred), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
#results without clipping values
[16.11809565]
[25.32843602]

#results after clipping values if there is a value less than epsilon (1e-7)
[16.11809565]
[16.11809565]
```

Comment: You got really sharp eyes and solid understanding on this.